# geom_area stacked plot. x-axis is date factor (months). y-axis is count of IDs. split by factor

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
str(data)
'data.frame':   2425838 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ ID     : int  10281466 10315034 11392679 12297599 20009616 110540620 114803146 115398695 120231006 130626270 ...
 $ factor1: chr  "<U+0630><U+0643><U+0631>""| __truncated__ "<U+0630><U+0643><U+0631>""| __truncated__ "<U+0630><U+0643><U+0631>""| __truncated__ "<U+0630><U+0643><U+0631>""| __truncated__ ...
 $ months : Date, format: "2015-07-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-07-01" ...
```

- The x-axis should be in months (each month is a tick mark).
- the y-axis is the count of IDs plotted per month.
- The chart should be a stacked area chart (similar to stacked area chart in excel (it is stacked because I want to display 2 stacked area charts one for each factor.

My problem is that I have many duplicates date values. How do I aggregate them, get the `ID_count`, and preserve factor distribution at the same time.

what I tried was:

```
ggplot(data) + geom_area(aes(x = as.Date(factor(months)), y=ID, stat='bin',
      fill = factor1, color=factor1), position = 'stack') +
      scale_x_date(breaks = "1 month", labels=date_format("%b,%y")) +
      theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust = 0))
```

`x = as.Date(factor(months)`: attempts to first place months in the x-axis with `factor(months)` which worked, but needed to further adjust using `scale_x_date`, which is why `i` is wrapped with `as.Date()` which failed.

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you wanted?

`d <- data.frame(day=as.Date('2015-09-16')+sample(-100:100, 500, r=T),
                id=sample(1:30, 500, r=T),
                factor=sample(c('a','b'), 500, r=T))
d <- aggregate(id ~ format(day, '%Y-%m') + factor, data=d, FUN=length)
colnames(d) <- c('month','factor','id_count')
ggplot(d, aes(x=month,y=id_count,group=factor,fill=factor))+ geom_area(position="stack")`

Comment: my problem is that I have many duplicates date values. How do I aggregate them, get the ID_count, and preserve factor distribution at the same time

Comment: `aggregate` function do it- object `d` id count of id splitted by month and factor variable